# Making check-list for some tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think about an idea of check-lists for some tags. Users who want to ask a new question with one of these tags have to answer some basic questions with yes/no answers. And only then they can post their question.

I talk about must-have checklist. For example: If I work with symfony I can ask question about sessions that are not working. I will tag this question with `php`, `symfony`, `sessions`. I (if I was newbie) can forget to do some basic checks. And if I was able to check it I could not start a new topic. Almost always users will comment this post withe next questions:

- "Did you clear your cache?"
- "Is your session dir is writable?" *This question will be asked only if there will be both `symfony` and `session` tags*
- "Are you working with dev environment?"

In almost any question this is the main problem of asker. He can solve his problem by just doing `php app/console cache:clear`. After that he will not delete his question. And some other user will ask again a new question where the best answer will be "Try to clear your cache". And there will a lot of questions that have no value for community at all.

We can avoid this by making check-lists for tags.

Just see next list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsymfony%5D+is%3Aanswer+cache%3Aclear

You will see that many questions have this as answer (not a comment), also in some of these answers author comment that it helped him but he didn't check the answer as right.

Comment: Who would create and maintain such checklists, who would define the conditions for showing the list, doesn't this feel like we're insulting users, who *have* done their research?

Answer (score 4):

This might work, but only if the site was *much* more structured. You would need a canonical question/answer for each thing in the checklist so that the OP could work out how to perform the instructions asked. Then, when the OP declined to bother reading the checklist you could immediately close as a duplicate of that one question.

That's going to be the problem. Given a long boring checklist which asks me* things I don't understand the chances of reading and understanding it all are minimal.

Equally, this assumes that there's a defined, definitive method of debugging every issue. We all know that's not true so you're going to annoy a significant number of people initially when there was no need to.

This feels like the sort of thing that should go into the tag wiki first. You can create a **How to debug** section, linking to the canonical questions in the order you want (they don't have to be your questions). Once this has been done then it might be something worth investigating in the future. This is something the community will have to do as you can't expect SE to have enough tag-specific expertise in order to come up with this list.

** Not* me *, but you get the picture.*